# Does the process of conditioning affect the conditioners?

Tags: conditioned

We are conditioned beings. Process of conditioning begins at a very early age and continues till we die.

My question is : Does the process of conditioning affect the conditioner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Buddhism, the word "a being" refers to a view that has been conditioned ([SN 23.2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn23/sn23.002.than.html); [SN 5.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn5.10/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=main&highlight=false)). It is not the "being" that engages in conditioning but is the arising of the notion/view of "a being" that is something conditioned.

The doctrine of Dependent Origination (described in SN 12.2) refers to three conditioners:

1. Body conditioner (kayasankharo; the breathing)
2. Verbal conditioner (vacisankharo; initial & sustained thought)
3. Mind conditioner (cittasankharo; perception & feeling).

The above three conditioners can get stirred up/proliferated by ignorance.

Therefore, the process of conditioning certainly affect the conditioners because the process of conditioning causes the conditioners to proliferate (eg. described in [SN 12.38](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.038.than.html))
.

For example, we are sitting calmly then suddenly there is an earthquake. The perception of the earthquake gives rise to a proliferation of other perceptions & feelings, many thoughts and causes the breathing to become flurried. This is an example of how the conditioners proliferate when there is ignorance & conditioning.